# PYsimpleGUI create a listbox of folders

Tags: user-interface, listbox, pysimplegui, getfiles

I am trying to modify the demoprogram from PYsimpleGUI (Browser_START_HERE_Demo_program_Browser.py) to:

- manually select a main folder
- list all the subfolders in that folder (but not the files inside them)
- make it possible to select a few of those folders, and list them as an output.

I thought I'd do so by editting the code for getting the file list dic, but everything I tried, just makes it

Any ideas? I attached it:

'''def get_file_list_dict():
"""
Returns dictionary of files
Key is short filename
Value is the full filename and path

```
:return: Dictionary of demo files
:rtype: Dict[str:str]
"""

demo_path = get_demo_path()
demo_files_dict = {}
for dirname, dirnames, filenames in os.walk(demo_path):
    for filename in filenames:
        if filename.endswith('.py') or filename.endswith('.pyw'):
            fname_full = os.path.join(dirname, filename)
            if filename not in demo_files_dict.keys():
                demo_files_dict[filename] = fname_full
            else:
                # Allow up to 100 dupicated names. After that, give up
                for i in range(1, 100):
                    new_filename = f'{filename}_{i}'
                    if new_filename not in demo_files_dict:
                        demo_files_dict[new_filename] = fname_full
                        break

return demo_files_dict'''
```

Answer (score 0):

It's much difficult for me to modify code of `Browser_START_HERE_Demo_program_Browser.py` to my requirements.

Assume the target is

- Select a main directory by a button to call function `sg.popup_get_folder`
- List all subdirectories under main directory in one `sg.Listbox`
- Subdirectories selected shown in another `sg.Listbox` as output when click  `Add` button

Example Code

```py
from pathlib import Path
import PySimpleGUI as sg

font = ("Courier New", 11)
sg.theme("Dark")
sg.set_options(font=font)

subfolders = []
selected = []

frame_subholders = [[sg.Listbox(subfolders, size=(80, 10), key='Subfolders',
    select_mode=sg.LISTBOX_SELECT_MODE_EXTENDED, enable_events=True,
    highlight_background_color='blue', highlight_text_color='white')]]
frame_selected = [[sg.Listbox(selected, size=(80, 10), key='Selected')]]

layout = [
    [sg.Input(readonly=True, expand_x=True, key='Main',
        disabled_readonly_background_color=sg.theme_input_background_color()),
     sg.Button("Main Folder")],
    [sg.Frame("Subholder", frame_subholders)],
    [sg.Frame("Selected subholder", frame_selected)],
    [sg.Button('Add')],
]

window = sg.Window('Title', layout, finalize=True)
entry = window['Main'].Widget
input_size = entry.winfo_width()//sg.Text.char_width_in_pixels(font)
print(input_size)

while True:

    event, values = window.read()
    if event == sg.WINDOW_CLOSED:
        break
    elif event == 'Main Folder':
        main_folder = sg.popup_get_folder("", no_window=True)
        if main_folder and Path(main_folder).is_dir():
            main_folder = main_folder.replace("/", '\\')        # For Windows
            half = input_size//2
            text = main_folder if len(main_folder) <= input_size else main_folder[:half-3]+"..."+main_folder[-half:]
            window['Main'].update(text)

            subfolders = sorted([str(f) for f in Path(main_folder).iterdir() if f.is_dir()])
            window['Subfolders'].update(values=subfolders)
            selected = []
            window['Selected'].update(values=selected)
    elif event == 'Add':
        selected = sorted([path for path in values['Subfolders']])
        window['Selected'].update(values=selected)

window.close()
```

[image]

Comment: Hi Jason. Thank you for your answer.yes this is almost exactly what I intended to make. Only instead of having selected files always enter the bottom listbox, only when clicking a button "add".

Comment: Just replace `elif event == 'Subfolders'` with `elif event == 'Add'`, and add one more element `sg.Button('Add')` into layout.

Comment: I have been trying but it gives me an error in:  <module>
    selected = sorted([path for path in values[event]])
KeyError: 'Add'

Comment: Oh, it should be `selected = sorted([path for path in values['Subfolders']])`. Update answer.